# Is there a way for implementing database migrations on Spring JPA without the use of frameworks (e.g.: flyway, liquidbase, etc)?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, migration

I'm migrating a system that used to be written in Jdbc Templates to Spring Data JPA. Before, we used to write the SQL queries ourselves, but now that we're modernizing our system, we're going to use Spring Data JPA for this. Due to restrictive factors, i can't implement a database migration framework, such as flyway and liquidbase. Is there any way i can implement those using what i have on Spring JPA?